# R.id. values get overwritten

Tags: android, webview

In my Android app I'm creating new `WebViews` from Java code; however after I create these WebViews my previously working id's get overwritten.

Example snippet:

```
for (int i=0;i<mywebviewarray.length;i++){
    mywebviewarray[i]=new WebView();
}
((Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton).settext("ok");
```

If I run this code, I get an exception on the last line:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.webkit.WebView

It seems to me as if the tables backing the `findViewById` get overwritten. I tried calling `setId` in the loop. but it does not help.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: More code needed. What is R.id.myButton , where are you setting the content view

Comment: try to rebuild your project : Project ==> Clean ==> Select your Project and press OK

Comment: add your xml file and 
I see that you said you tried set id in the loop but what did you set them to?
try `mywebviewarray[i].setId(String.valueOf(i));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not solving this problem, and instead of using a dynamic array of WebViews, I ended up using fixed 3 WebViews. I'm changing their content like a 3-length window over an array of URLs, thus simulating the original concept. (Albeit in a slower way)

Answer (score 2):

What is in mywebviewarray. It seems to me like you have something in there that isnt a WebView and you are trying to instantiate it as a WebView.

Comment: WebView[] mywebviewarray = new WebView[5];

The exception is thrown on the findViewById line. I checked it multiple times. R.id.mybutton refers to a button in my main.xml. I tried reverse testing too: 
((WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybutton)).loadUrl("about:blank"); 
succeeds (!).